# Where to start with Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This question only needs one answer: a list of great resources for getting started with Oracle, including Database Administration, PL/SQL and SQL.

You may find your question has been closed as a duplicate of this one, if so, please don't be offended: we are trying to be as helpful as we can without [diluting the expert focus of this site](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/757/1396). Closing a question as a duplicate of this one is us saying "What you *really* need is to spend some time reading some of the best resources available rather than have your *specific* question answered right now. If you do get through these resources, you'll soon be back with more [advanced questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: If you are curious why this question exists, please see [this on meta](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/1081/1396) and [this discussion in The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/conversation/concerning-a-duplicate-target-for-too-basic-questions).

Answer (score 18):

Oracle's official [documentation library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/index.htm) has some great resources, including:

- The [Database Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17633/toc.htm) guide, which is essential reading for beginner and Oracle ninja alike.
- The [2 Day DBA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17643/toc.htm)
- The [2 Day Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e21814/toc.htm)

Oracle 12c official PL/SQL documentation:

- [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/toc.htm)
- [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/toc.htm)
- [Chapter 5 Developing Stored Subprograms and Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e21814/tdddg_subprograms.htm) from [2 Day Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e21814/toc.htm)

PL/SQL 101

This is a twelve part series of articles on understanding and using PL/SQL. It is written by Steven Feuerstein and published in Oracle Magazine.

1. [Building with Blocks](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21plsql-242570.html)
2. [Controlling the Flow of Execution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-jul/o41plsql-402935.html)
3. [Working with Strings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51plsql-453456.html)
4. [Working with Numbers in PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61plsql-512011.html)
5. [Working with Dates in PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jan/o12plsql-1408561.html)
6. [Error Management](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-mar/o22plsql-1518275.html)
7. [Working with Records](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-may/o32plsql-1578019.html)
8. [Working with Collections](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html)
9. [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html)
10. [The Data Dictionary: Make Views Work for You](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-nov/o62plsql-1851968.html)
11. [Wrap Your Code in a Neat Package](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13plsql-1872456.html)
12. [Working with Cursors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

Comment: Please feel free to edit in others that come to mind or add your own specific advice useful to the kind of people likely to end up here.

Answer (score 5):

I like this one:

[Oracle Magazine SQL 101](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/index-1429427.html)